# Cloned a WP site which had https:// and now can't access wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

I coned a wordpress site which had https:// and SSL to another domain.

This domain has no SSL.

The site works okay except the /wp-admin login says page not found. Tired changing SITE URL back to http:// in wp-config and functions.php but now even on http:// it says page not found. Any ideas?

Comment: Let me know if you still have wp-admin access to the original site and if you do, I'll suggest a workaround.

Comment: Did you check the .htaccess file for old redirects that need to be deleted?

Comment: Thanks, got it sorted through .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database check the table `options`, There are two options calld `siteurl` and `home`, update these to the new URL.

If that is fixed, check your `.htaccess`. This could contain rewrite rules and redirects regarding `wp-admin`.

In the `config.php` set the following to false:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

There might be other causes, but the ones I've listed above are quite common.